# Jackson JSON deserialize wrapped property (discard envelope)

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I have the following JSON structure

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
           "title" : "My Title",
           "description" : "My Description"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which is whats returned from Elastic Search when I search my index for a book.

A book is defined as a java type:

```
class Book {
    private String title;
    private String description;

    //...Getters and setters
}
```

So in the json, _source is effectively the Book. I'd like to deserialize the structure to be a Book, I guess using some kind of implementation of a JsonDeserializer. I have tried quite a few different ways without any success, and cant find any decent documentation on the subject online, all I can figure is that I probably need to implement ResolvableDeserializer but have no idea how to implement its resolve method or even what is does! Has anyone got any ideas of the best way to do this or a link to an explanation?

Cheers
NFV

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a special `JsonDeserializer` for this. Your class is a simple java bean and Jackson can handle those automatically. Look at the documentation for the [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) project.

Comment: I realize that Jackson Databinding can handle Beans out of the box, but the point im having difficulty with is how to get it to disregard the envelope? I thought something like @JsonRootName("_source") may do it but no luck.

Comment: The whole thing? Like hits.hits._source? Alright, that wasn't really clear from the question ;)

Comment: Sorry about that, yeah id like to disregard hits.hits, only getting the _source element (which is the Book). Also notice that hits.hits is an array of _source elements, although hits.hits.length == 1 always. Im thinking on the lines of a customised BeanDeserializer or ResolvableDeserializable but cant find any documentation on how to use these?